# How to show audio details when played using MediaPlayerLauncher?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my application i am playing an audio file (let it be .mp3) using MediaPlayerLauncher. File is downloaded from network and stored in IsolatedStorage.
I managed to play the audio but it was a bit disapointing to see that there is absolutly no details about the played track.

Is there a way to show picture and/or track name when launched with MediaPlayerLauncher? Or am i forced to use MediaElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you're just playing an audio stream using the MediaPlayerLauncher there si no way to specifyu additional (meta) data for the launcher to also display.
If you want additional information displayed then you'll need to create the UI yourself and play the track via a MediaElement (or background audio).